# How can I dump the whole screen when using ADB?

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator

I am trying to get the Hierarchy of the whole screen using ADB.

If I used adb shell uiautomator dump, I only get the current view and not the whole screen. For example if I dump the current view, and I scroll down and dump again, I will get a different output. I want to dump the whole screen without having to scroll down and dump again.

Comment: Um, you already are getting "the whole screen". Scrolling changes the screen content, so you naturally get different results. That is no different than getting different results because you typed text in a field or checked a radio button.

Comment: I guess my wording is a little off. I want to get the Hierarchy of all elements that are in the page without having to scroll. Is that possible?

Comment: You already are getting all the elements that are in the "page". What is it that you are trying to scroll? Is it a `RecyclerView`? A `ListView`? A `WebView`? Something else?

Comment: For example if I am using the gmail app, in my inbox I have a list of emails that are currently in my view. Dumping will only give me that list of email, I want to know if there is a way of getting all emails in my inbox.

Scrolling down in this case would be swiping up to reveal more emails in the list.

Comment: As you said everything on the "page", for those elements that are not in the page android is not responsible. I mean for example viewholder of recyclerView is only holding the data of fields that are showing in the screen and not holding the data for off-screen fields, therefor there is nothing out of screen and they will be serve only when they come to screen for example by scrolling.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I am using the gmail app, in my inbox I have a list of emails that are currently in my view. Dumping will only give me that list of email, I want to know if there is a way of getting all emails in my inbox.

Generally, no.

Using your Gmail example, suppose that the Gmail app is showing the conversations in some label, and that label contains 343,140,189 conversations.

(spam, amirite?)

I am guessing that you think that the UI of the Gmail app has a scrolling list with 343,140,189 rows in it, and that scrolling just changes which of those 343,140,189 rows are visible.

That is not the case, for lots of reasons, such as the app running out of memory.

Most scrolling lists in Android use classes like `RecyclerView` and `ListView`. These classes recycle their rows. So, instead of 343,140,189 rows, there will be a handful, enough to fill the screen and perhaps a couple more. As the user scrolls, and rows roll off the screen, they get recycled: populated with new content and fed in as "new" rows. Visually, the effect is indistinguishable from having 343,140,189 rows. From a programming standpoint, the difference is significant. And from a `uiautomator` standpoint, the programming is what matters.